# Pattern string with repetition

Tags: combinatorics

How many license plate with the following pattern?

$$LL DDD LL$$

where L is a letter chosen from $\{A,B,\dots,Z\}$ (26 letters) and D is a digit chosen from $\{0,1,2,\dots,9\}$ (10 digits, zero is allowed).

The answer is $26^2 \times 10^3 \times 26^2$ because repetition of letters and digits are permitted. But what about double counting, why not divide for all cases like $AA$ $111$ $AA$ where we count more that one permutation of the same letter and digit  (in this case A and one )?

My solution is $\frac{26^2 \times 10^3 \times 26^2}{2! \times 3! \times 2!}$.

Exemples of valid string:

$$AB123CD$$
$$AA000AA$$
$$AA111BC$$

Comment: You yourself said that repetition is allowed. Where is double counting?

Comment: @LightYagami For example the string AA123BC is counted two time. In fact Aa123BC and aA123BC even it they are the same plates (i used lower case just to show)

Comment: No, the way the answer $26^{2} \times 10^{3} \times 26^{2}$ is written means that for the first letter you have $26$ options to take, then again for the second letter, you have $26$ options to take and then we have $10$ options to take a number and so on... I don't understand how is that double counting?

Comment: @LightYagami Problem solved below!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The given answer is correct. Think about generating the two letters in front like this: first you can pick any of the available letters to go into the first slot, a total of $26$ options. Then, pick any letter again to go in the second slot, again $26$ choices. If you think about choosing one letter before the other, it should be clear that we're only counting each combination once.

Comment: Ok now i clear!!! Basically once i have choose a letter o digit I cannot go back to the same "spot". Ahhhh. Thank so much!! Sorry but I just started Combinatorics. Studying math alone is not that easy...

Comment: No worries, I'm happy to help. Have a nice day!